# Need to update table asynchronously with data from api Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, axios

I am trying to fetch data from the db asynchronously whenever a new field is updated but even after adding the necessary async and await keyword the table gets updated only on page load.

I have a form to submit data to the db and i want the table to be updated as soon as it happens

Code to update table

```
const entryList = []
const [tableEntries, setTableEntries] = React.useState(entryList)

useEffect(() => {
async function fetchMyAPI() {
await Axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/connections')
 .then(res => {
  const newList =  entryList.concat(res.data);
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(newList, response => {
    setTableEntries(prevTableEntries => [...prevTableEntries,response]);
  });
 })
 .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

fetchMyAPI()

}, []);
```

Code to display data inside of the table

```
{ tableEntries.map((item) => (
              <>
              <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>{item.id}</td>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>{item.connectionType}</td>
              <td>
                <CDropdown className="m-1" size="lg">
                  <CDropdownToggle color="secondary">
                    Select Option
                  </CDropdownToggle>
                  <CDropdownMenu>
                    <CDropdownItem>Delete</CDropdownItem>
                    <CDropdownItem>Reauthorize</CDropdownItem>
                  </CDropdownMenu>
                </CDropdown>
              </td>
              </tr>
              </>
            ))}
```

Code for form submission (Including this incase this was necessary for you guys to understand)

```
async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // stop browser from submitting form
    const form = await event.target; // get form element
    const article = { "connectionType": "InstagramConnection", "name": this.state.value, "accessCredentials": { "id": 2, "token": this.state.access_token } };
    await Axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/connections', article)
    .then(response => console.log(response.data))
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('There was an error!', error);
    })
  }
```

(EDIT: Added the variables which i am using for updating the table to the code able for easier reference)

Comment: Read this article, it'll help you to understand about dependency array used in useEffect. https://dev.to/aasthapandey/useeffect-in-react-3flb

Comment: `whenever a new field is updated` as in "whenever the form is submitted"? If yes, why not actually do what you want to do instead of just `console.log(response.data)`? Expand the callback to also update the table. Note that you can return the table data as reply to the POST request, provided you set it up accordingly on the backend.

Comment: What is `entryList`?

Comment: The thing is the form submission and the table being displayed are happening in 2 separate components.. i just added the form submission code as a reference but the main point of concern for me is the code to display the table and fetching data from api

Comment: EntryList is a const list variable i had declared to store incoming entries from the api

Comment: In that case you need https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: @PradipDhakal I actually tried using a dependency array by using entry list but now its updating the table infinitely without the form submission

Comment: The dependency array approach only makes sense if the useEffect function is updating a *different* state. Otherwise you'll get an infinite loop.

Comment: @ChrisG I am not sure how i can use the Lifting state up which you had mentioned in this case

Comment: You said `The thing is the form submission and the table being displayed are happening in 2 separate components` and this problem is solved by lifting state up. It's an essential mechanism.